# Merge matching line with following lines until next match

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file which looks like this:

```
# foo
100
202
# bar
330
119
111
# baz
# qux
193
```

And I want to transform it into:

```
foo:100
foo:202
bar:330
bar:119
bar:111
qux:193
```

Which command should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest awk. If a line starts with `#` save second column to variable `a`. If column starts with a digit print content of variable `a`and append `:` with current line (`$0`).

```
awk '/^#/{a=$2}; /^[0-9]/{print a":"$0}' file
```

Output:

```
foo:100
foo:202
bar:330
bar:119
bar:111
qux:193
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/^# /{s///;h;d};G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2:\1/p' file
```

If the line in the pattern space (PS) begins with a `#` followed by a space, remove those characters and store the result in the hold space (HS) and delete that line. Otherwise, append the HS to the PS, match the values either side of the introduced newline and swap them using a `:` as a separator.